# Handle every possible UTI in an OS X application

Tags: macos, cocoa, uti

How do I make an OS X app respond to any possible document UTI as an editor? That is, it should be capable of handling any file dragged to its Dock icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UTI `public.data` to handle all files.

(Do *not* use `public.item`; weird things will happen.)