# How to support/assing ALL file types (UTIs) in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios6, uidocumentinteraction

I'm developing something like file manager for remote filesystem with some basic operations including transferring file(s) between server and iPad and viewing them.

In order to be useful I need my app to open all types of files from other apps (like Mail, Safari, etc.) via "Open in.." dialog to get them into my app, i. e. Dropbox-like behaviour. When I use `public.data` and `public.content`, like it is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017468/ios-document-file-type-associations-wildcard-uti) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050026/handle-every-possible-uti-in-an-os-x-application)), it sometimes work, but most of the time, it isn't. Moreover, iOS 6.1 simulator behaves nondeterministic regarding file handling.

When I Run in Xcode and it launches simulator, it doesn't work. When I let simulator running, Stop in Xcode and then Run in Xcode, it suddenly work. When I completely quit simulator and Run in Xcode I get at start of this loop. Mysterious.

When I run app on physical iPad with iOS 6 and start Safari or Mail and go to some document or attachment in it, **[Open in...]** dialog appears including my app but tapping does nothing, no reaction.

My goal is to make it work for iOS from 5.1 up.

- Base SDK: iOS 6.1
- Target: 5.1

I'm rookie here on SO. Although I've read instruction how to write good questions, help me improve my question if you feel it is needed, please.

Comment: Did you try it on a real iOS device?

Comment: I have real device with iOS 5.1 and from time to time somebody test it on real device with iOS 6.1. If I remember, originally there was only `public.data` and `public.content` and Open In.. had been displayed including my app then, but when the man with 6.1 tapped on it, nothing happened...

Answer (score 1):

Using `public.item`, in documentation:

[image]

[Documentation UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-SW5)